# what is the package of curl library?

Tags: linux

i use ubuntu 14.04. i have a program and get the following 3 error messages during compilation.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

i searched in google and after installing libssl-dev with

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

command i only have the following line in logs.

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcurl
```

How can i install curl and get rid of this message.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `libcurl4-openssl-dev`, or one of the other flavours if you need it.